# ARKit – Pivot Point of 3D model is wrong

Tags: xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality, blender, arkit

I´m using Blender to export my models to `dae` and Xcode to import it to `scn`.
But my problem is that the pivot point is totally wrong placed
when I use it in my scene.
The strange thing is that the pivot point is positioned right in
the model viewer from SceneKit (even as `scn`).
The World Coordinates are all zeroed.

Answer (score 1):

Group all the elements of your 3D model in Blender and move your pivot point for that group at a desired place. SceneKit always reads in a position of pivot point in 99.99% correctly.

Even if you have just one 3D object – group it in Blender. SceneKit sees hierarchy in `dae` file and respects group's pivot. So, your pivot's position in SceneKit will be the same as in Blender.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its only 1 element. 
Scenekit seems to read the pivot point correctly yes.
But it seems like xcode interprets its position wrong :/

Comment: Could you publish a screenshot from Blender and from SceneKit? What do you mean "interpreted wrong"?

Comment: Here ^^
http://snap.ashampoo.com/uploads/2018-10-01/PoIQtY4DUKSJbe6f1URLcjnVv1AykbwZpalDYihOS1yu9wzzLLgovTELOFEYG3tV.png
Also i select only selection when i export it.
So its nothing else in the dae.
I cant get my hands on SceneKit atm. But i know i did nothing special at binding it in. With some models it works magically :/

Comment: I dont have the same group function as in maya i think.
I got this option to group up (Just an empty object):
http://snap.ashampoo.com/uploads/2018-10-01/HzVfekcqWNCOmlbGbpGBGfkOz0MatyC2SyAxDdi1Qlk6wleX2lzcqErKe8KXxNtK.png
And this (STRG + G) (But i cant set a position for this this group):
http://snap.ashampoo.com/uploads/2018-10-01/6Tyk9Y8ReXzg6BRLcarOTicsO2UgIigG49r3yPo5IiDgkvRmve3kM854zsdC1jJx.png

Comment: You've got the same group function in Blender as in Maya.

Comment: Press ctrl+G, you will notice a green outline appear around them. Now in future, if you wish to manipulate the whole group: Select a member of the group and then press shift+G and press Group and it will select every other object in that group which you can now drag around, scale etc.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object